Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
Issues connecting client to server.
Server on port 3000 and app on port 5001 via Live Server:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oz_5Qur' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The error message repeats every second or so.
I've tried looking through many similar posts to no avail.
Expected result: A "user connected" terminal log when a new connection is made and a log when the user disconnects.
index.js (server)
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join } from 'node:path';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

app.use(cors()); 
app.use('/socket.io', express.static(join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'socket.io', 'client-dist')));
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'myapp')));
console.log(__dirname);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:5001/");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'server.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});

client.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    </script>
</body>
</html>

server.html (no issues)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
</body>
</html>


if you app.use(cors()); why are you also manually adding CORS headers?

Good catch. But, removing app.use(cors()) does not change anything.

That's not the one I would've removed - you haven't shown browser code that uses XMLHttpRequest, so

Removing the manually set CORS headers doesn't fix the issue either, if that's the one you would've removed.

Does this answer your question? Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/

You need to define cors for your socket server as shown below in your index.js (server) file.
You can also use origin: ['http://localhost:3000] instead of origin: '*' if you want to allow only http://localhost:3000
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      credentials: true,
    }
  });

